# How to generate code with custom templates?

Tags: code-generation

Is there any tool to generate code (text files) with custom templates which I define?
For example it should have possibility to include multiple templates of some functions (which I can specify and parameterize) and put them in one class file template.

Do you know any advanced software which help me with that? 
File templates in IDE (like Webstorm) are too simple for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own tool for this.

- parameterized with json file
- use Apache Velocity templates

https://github.com/latata/simple-code-generator

Answer (score 6):

**Telosys** could help you, it's a code generator 
working with **customizable templates** (Velocity templates).
You can also create your own templates.
Telosys is available as a simple Command Line Interface tool and as an Eclipse Plugin. Everything is Open Source (tool and templates).

See the main web site http://www.telosys.org/
and Eclipse Plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

The customizable templates are available on GitHub (https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3).

Answer (score 3):

I use Telosys (http://www.telosys.org/) to generate Python code.

It works fine. You can use it to generate any kind of text file.

Answer (score 0):

check this one https://code.gencode.net you can generate code from simple text templates and SQL server, the output files can be in any programming language.

This is a tool I have developed and personally use to generate the code for all CRUD files an application may need, basically gets database information, field names, datatypes, foreign keys ,primary keys and merges your text templates replacing variables between [], also have sections that can be iterated like fields names in a class or stored procedure, these are replaced in the main template, more information on how it works can be found in www.gencode.net and also there are some sample templates that can be used to see how it works

Answering the question since templates are based on your own code you can add references to custom functions, classes, security validations, anything you want in the templates. Also you can have multiple templates, include them in a group of templates, and include these groups in a project, which has the link to the SQL database

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)